# SSMS stuck scripting database objects

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, scripting

SQL Server Management Studio sits stuck, after scripting all objects in a database. Except it didn't script all objects in a database.

i scripted all the objects in an SQL Server 2008 database from SQL Server Management Studio (three times):

[image]

And it says it scripted all the objects, except it never actually completes - sitting there stuck:

[image]

It does manage to script **three** objects:

[image]

But not all the objects.

You'll notice:

- the UI says it sucessfully scripted all 189 objects
- the UI is stuck; the Close button is disabled
- the folder that contains the "successfully" scripted database objects doesn't contain all the successfully scripted database objects.

Which begs the question:

> How do i script the objects of an SQL Server 2008 databasein SSMS?

**Update**: It can script any `VIEW`, `STORED PROCEDURE`, or `FUNCTION`, without issue. But if i choose to script just the first table, it fails:

[image]

It also fails if i script tables:

- `A` - `M`
- `O` - `Z`
- `A` - `G`

This never-ending bug was the reason we bought SQL Compare four years ago; you couldn't trust Microsoft's tool to script a database correctly (silently omitting tables).

## **Update:** Scripting options

Here's the set of scripting options in use

- **ANSI Padding: True**
- Append to File: False
- Continue scripting on Error: False
- Convert UDDTs to Base Types: False
- Generate Script for Dependent Objects: False
- **Include Descriptive Headers: True**
- Include If NOT EXISTS: False
- Include system constraint names: False
- **Schema qualify object names.: True**
- Script Bindings: False
- **Script Collation: True**
- **Script Create: True**
- **Script Defaults: True**
- Script Drop: False
- **Script Extended Properties: True**
- Script for Server Version: SQL Server 2008
- Script Logins: False
- Script Object-Level Permissions: False
- Script Statistics: Script statistics
- **Script USE DATABASE: True**
- Script Change Tracking: False
- **Script Check Contraints: True**
- Script Data: False
- Script Data Compression Options: False
- **Script Foreign Keys: True**
- **Script Full-Text Indexes: True**
- **Script Indexes: True**
- **Script Primary Keys: True**
- **Script Triggers: True**
- **Script Unique Keys: True**

[image]

---

- My related question from 4 years ago: [SQL Server Management Studio not scripting all objects](https://serverfault.com/questions/66854/sql-server-management-studio-not-scripting-all-objects)

Comment: Does it complete for any other output options?

Comment: It *does* complete if i use `Single file`.

Comment: @sqluillman Interesting, it also completes if i script views, functions, or stored procedures. But as soon as i script a table: it fails to complete.

Comment: Can you list the advanced scripting options you have set to true?  This comes from the step after you select which objects to script out.

Comment: Shoot, that might be a 2008 R2 thing.  I don't have straight-up 2008 available right now...  Do you see something in the wizard that lets you set more options?  Things like ansi padding, generate drop and create, include If NOT EXISTS, etc.  I can't remember the wizard from 2008 off the top of my head...

Comment: @squillman Those options are there *"ANSI Padding: True"*, *"Script Create: True"*, *"Include If NOT EXISTS: False"* ...

Comment: The same thing happens here. Using SQL 2012